# Possible to have two different checkout processes (and payment processors)?

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, onepage-checkout, countries

I've been tasked with creating a checkout process for a country other than the one we normally do business in.  This other country has a completely different process for CC payments, so I'm going to have to build a completely custom checkout process for the country.

Is it possible to have a unique checkout process per Magento website? Or do I need to create a whole new Magento installation and make the other country's site there?

I've looked around and couldn't find anything concrete. [This](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/383/when-using-multistore-is-it-possible-to-have-different-checkout-configurations) Magento answer doesn't apply since what I'm asking is different than the linked question.  I've also thought that I could make the other country's checkout in a new module, and have that module enabled or disabled on a per-website basis, but the only place I've seen someone try it was [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-activatedeactivate-magento-module-per-a-website-level/) and the comments mention that turning on caching breaks this hack.

Any insights would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Although a little late, but, Yes, that's entirely possible. I am assuming you are having different websites. You can try with different themes for them. Shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Put that into an answer and I'll mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have different website setups for different countries, you can surely achieve what you are trying. To have different payment processors, you can have them from admin configuration only, enable payment methods at website levels.

To achieve different checkout process, you'll need to modify checkout templates in respective themes for different websites, they can share same code logic, only their design will differ.